# List of Ask Ubuntu uses within the Ubuntu community?

Tags: discussion

Can anyone provide a list of places that Ask Ubuntu is being used to enhance the Ubuntu community?

This is intended as a community wiki question for us to collect and celebrate the use other parts of the Ubuntu community are making of us.

Comment: Doesn't the FAQ say to still phrase it in the form of a question?  Should the "answer" be in an answer instead of in the question?

Answer (score 8):

[omgubuntu.co.uk](http://omgubuntu.co.uk) now has a cool sidebar on each page with AU questions and answers, and it looks pretty slick too:

[image]

Comment: Cool - I hadn't noticed that before.

Answer (score 5):

Launchpad mentions AU on the reporting a bug page:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

- [Ubuntu One's support page](https://one.ubuntu.com/support/) lists us as the first place to ask for help, and contains a link to the relevant tag page.
- The [homepages](http://unity.ubuntu.com/projects/) of each of the Unity family projects (Unity, Application Indicators, uTouch and Notify OSD) contains a prominent "Frequently Asked Questions" link to the relevant tag page. In fact Ask Ubuntu links have be sprinkled over all of [unity.ubuntu.com](http://unity.ubuntu.com/)